# Get records based on column max value

Tags: sql, oracle

I have cars table with data

```
country | car      | price
---------------------
Germany | Mercedes | 30000
Germany | BMW      | 20000
Germany | Opel     | 15000
Japan   | Honda    | 20000
Japan   | Toyota   | 15000
```

I need get country, car      and  price from table, with highest price
for each country

```
Germany Mercedes    30000
Japan   Honda       20000
```

Comment: What if you have two cars with the max price in a country? WIll you get all these rows or only one ( which one?) ?

Comment: Yes all these rows in this case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try

```
    select cars.* FROM cars
    INNER JOIN (
        select country, max(price) AS maxprice from cars 
        GROUP BY country
    ) m
    ON cars.country = m.country AND cars.price = m.maxprice
```

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I need

Answer (score 1):

Use `ROW_NUMBER()`

```
 SELECT *
 FROM ( SELECT *, 
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY country
                                  ORDER BY price DESC) as rn
        FROM cars ) as T
 WHERE T.rn = 1
```

If you allow ties, use [RANK](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions123.htm) instead

```
 SELECT *
 FROM ( SELECT *, 
               RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY country
                            ORDER BY price DESC) as rn
        FROM cars ) as T
 WHERE T.rn = 1
```