# Get records based on column max value - in PySpark

Tags: pyspark, bigdata

I have cars table with data

| country | car | price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Germany | Mercedes | 30000 |
| Germany | BMW | 20000 |
| Germany | Opel | 15000 |
| Japan | Honda | 20000 |
| Japan | Toyota | 15000 |

I need get country, car and price from table, with highest price for each country

| country | car | price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Germany | Mercedes | 30000 |
| Japan | Honda | 20000 |

I saw similar question but solution there is in SQL, i want DSL format of that for PySpark dataframes (link in case for that: [Get records based on column max value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42954093/get-records-based-on-column-max-value))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `row_number` and `filter` to achieve your result like below

```
df = spark.createDataFrame(
[
("Germany","Mercedes", 30000),
("Germany","BMW", 20000),
("Germany","Opel", 15000),
("Japan","Honda",20000),
("Japan","Toyota",15000)], 
("country","car", "price"))

from pyspark.sql.window import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import row_number, desc

df1 = df.withColumn("row_num", row_number().over(Window.partitionBy("country").orderBy(desc("price"))))


df2 = df1.filter(df1.row_num == 1).drop('row_num')
```